# Check if dataframe contain Date or Time

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I want to check if dataframe contain a date or datetime value in python dataframe. It is possible to do it ?

```
df = {'Latitude':['19.34', '19.42', '-4.34', '35.10'], 
      'Date':['2019-03-13', '2016-07-08', '2018-03-08', '2014-01-17']}
```

and make a function to check date

```
def CheckDate():

    return True




CheckDate(df)
True
```

Comment: Try `pd.Series('2019-03-13').isin(df.Date)[0]`

Comment: you want to check for a specific date or if there is a date column in your df ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code to check if a given date exists in a dataframe:

```
yourdate = '2018-03-08'
print((df['Date'] == yourdate).any())
```

output:

```
True
```

Alternatively, you can try this:

```
print('2018-03-08' in df['Date'].values)
```

output:

```
True
```

**Desired Code**:

```
def checkDate(df, date):
    if date in df['Date'].values:
        return True
    return False

df = pd.DataFrame({'Latitude':['19.34', '19.42', '-4.34', '35.10'], 
                   'Date':['2019-03-13', '2016-07-08', '2018-03-08', '2014-01-17']})
print(checkDate(df, '2018-03-08'))
print(checkDate(df, '2018-03-09'))
```

output:

```
True
False
```

You can also write you function like this:

```
def checkDate(df, date):
       return date in df['Date'].values
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `in`:

```
df = {'Latitude':['19.34', '19.42', '-4.34', '35.10'], 
      'Date':['2019-03-13', '2016-07-08', '2018-03-08', '2014-01-17']} 

'2019-03-13' in df['Date']
True

'2019-03-30' in in df['Date']
False
```

In function it would look like this:

```
def checkDate(df, date)
    return date in df['Date']
```